# Can I log into other Stack Exchange sites using my Stack Overflow ID?

Tags: support, login

I don't really understand how I'm logged into Stack Overflow. It's just always logged in. But I can't use my email address or Google account to log in to [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Do I need to create a separate account for each Stack Exchange site?

Comment: If you sign up to another Stack Exchange site using the same Google account or Stack Exchange login, a new account will be created on that website which will be "associated" with your Stack Overflow account.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that no, you can't. But if you log in the same way, it'll associate the accounts together. Since I didn't know how I was logged in, to find out:

1) I selected "Log in using Stack Exchange" and "forgot my password" and entered my email address.

2) It sent me an email telling me that I don't have an account with that address but that I do have one using Google login.

3) Then I  went back to the login page and logged in using Google login, and it created an account and associated it with my Stack Overflow account.

Comment: Note that the help center has several articles on how to manage your account. It explains the existence of a singular SE profile and the linkage of different accounts. http://stackoverflow.com/help/account

Answer (score 1):

This is now being changed to be a lot easier and more unified. See the MSE post about it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/upcoming-login-changes-stage-2-now-live?cb=1).

The short answer is that you should be automatically signed into any accounts which you already have accounts with, and there's now a single button press to confirm creating a new account on sites where you don't have an account yet.